# Call useSWR by previous useSWR data.map then got Error(useSWR to get google calendar event)

Tags: reactjs, google-calendar-api, swr, usehooks-ts

I write a hook named useGoogleCalendarEvents, Try to get users google calendar event,below is my code.

```
import { Schedule, User } from '../../types/commons.type';
import { useLocalStorage } from 'usehooks-ts';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { FetchCalendarList } from '../../types/googleCalendarAPIResponse.type';
import { currentUTCMonthString } from '../../utils/DateUtils';

const baseURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3';

const fetcher = ([path, method, body = {}, accessToken = '']: [string, string, object, string]) => {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'].includes(method) ? 'application/json' : '',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  };
  const fetchOptions = {
    method,
    headers,
    body: method === 'GET' ? undefined : JSON.stringify(body),
  };
  const apiURL = `${baseURL}${path}`;
  return fetch(apiURL, fetchOptions).then((r) => r.json());
};

export const useGoogleCalendarEvents = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useLocalStorage<User | undefined>('user', undefined);

  const events: Array<string> = [];

  if (user?.googleAccessToken) {
    // get user calendar list
    const { data: GoogleCalendarListResult } = useSWR<FetchCalendarList>(
      ['/users/me/calendarList', 'GET', {}, user?.googleAccessToken],
      fetcher,
    );

    const { startString, endString } = currentUTCMonthString();
    const parameters = `timeMin=${startString}&timeMax=${endString}`;
    // map loop to get event by calendar id
    GoogleCalendarListResult?.items?.map((calendar) => {
      const { data: GoogleCalendarEventResult } = useSWR(
        [`/calendars/${calendar.id}/events?${parameters}`],
        fetcher,
      );
    });
  }
  return { events };
};
```

the code not yet finish but i got the error

> "React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by MySettingPage2."

I modify the code

```
GoogleCalendarListResult?.items?.map((calendar) => {
      const { data: GoogleCalendarEventResult } = useSWR(
        [`/calendars/${calendar.id}/events?${parameters}`],
        fetcher,
      );    });
```

to

```
['calendarid1', 'calendarid2'].map((calendar) => {
      const { data: GoogleCalendarEventResult } = useSWR(
        [`/calendars/${calendar.id}/events?${parameters}`],
        fetcher,
      );
    });
```

It is work, but not flexble. I want to get calendar id list first, then get envets by calendar id

Is anybody known why cause this error? Thank for any reply

Comment: you may want to google that message theres a few questions on stack overflow already that address "React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by XXX"